# How to parse this boolean contained JSON output with jq?

Tags: json, jq

The JSON output I am trying to parse:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "aa": [
      {
        "timestamp": 123456,
        "price": 1
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 123457,
        "price": 2
    ],
    "bb": [
      {
        "timestamp": 123456,
        "price": 3
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 123457,
        "price": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So after banging my head against the wall a million times, I just removed the *"success": true",* line from the output and I could easily do jq stuff with it. Otherwise if I ran for example:

```
cat jsonfile.json | jq -c .[].aa
```

I would get:

> Cannot index boolean with string "aa"

Which makes sense, since the first key is boolean. But I have no clue how to skip it while processing with jq.

Goal is to filter only timestamp and price of "aa", without giving any care about the "success": true key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `data` field first: `jq .data.aa[]`

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I did not find this solution myself. Simple and makes total sense.
Feel ashamed.
Hope this can help someone else one day!

Comment: Sometimes we look so hard we don't see. Everyone in this field has been there!